# Does SettingWithCopyWarning even matter?

Tags: python, pandas

I add values to a dataframe entry by entry as followed:

```
refined_cme_quandl_list['typical_daily_volume']= np.nan
for index, row in refined_cme_quandl_list.iterrows():
    refined_cme_quandl_list['typical_daily_volume'][index] = typical_volume[row['Quandl_download_symbol']]
```

I still get what i want, but i get this warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Does it matter?

Comment: Yes. You should use `.loc` to assign to slices.

Comment: You should "see the caveats in the documentation..." as suggested by the warning and determine if it matters in your case.

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/7306999

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using boolean indexing directly to assign to slices is not recommended. Use `df.loc` instead:

```
refined_cme_quandl_list.loc[index, 'typical_daily_volume'] = \
                              typical_volume[row['Quandl_download_symbol']]
```

It is quite possible that future releases of pandas might disable this behaviour (direct indexing), so you don't want your code breaking in the future.

Comment: Exactly. The behaviour could even vary depending on the release of `numpy` or `python` (or other `pandas` dependencies) that you're using.  Because the documentation says about code that throws a `SettingWithCopyWarning`: "Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees)"